# How to enable a pure Python module instead of a C accelerated version for a stdlib module such as datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-import

Some stdlib modules (such as `datetime`, `decimal`, `io`) have both C and pure Python implementations e.g., see [PEP 399 -- Pure Python/C Accelerator Module Compatibility Requirements](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0399/).

It might be desirable to disable the C accelerated version.

For `decimal`, `io` modules I can import `_pydecimal` and `_pyio` modules directly. How to get access to the pure Python `datetime` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C accelarated version (`_datetime`) is enabled in `datetime.py` using `from _datetime import *` and therefore it is enough to cause ImportError and reload the datetime module in case it has been already imported earlier:

```
import importlib
import sys

sys.modules['_datetime'] = None # cause ImportError
datetime = importlib.reload(importlib.import_module('datetime'))
```

Test:

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(1<<30)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/datetime.py", line 430, in __new__
    raise OverflowError("timedelta # of days is too large: %d" % d)
OverflowError: timedelta # of days is too large: 1073741824
```

The traceback shows that the pure Python version is used.